# How to access the text of a remotely loaded "<script>" element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Well i am currently trying to write an ajax enabled Manga reader application for onemanga using greasemonkey (more precisely js / jquery)

my problem is that i need to execute one of the inline scripts on their page to update the next page url. so what i attempted was the following:

```
$.get(nextPage,function(nxtHtm) // the variable nextPage already contains required url
{
  nxtImgUrl = $(nxtHtm).find(".one-page img").attr("src");   // get next image url
  $("body").append("<img id='dynamic' src='"+nxtImgUrl+"'/>");  // append next image
  $(nxtHtm).find("script:last-1").appendTo("body"); // attempt to append script to body
  alert(nextPage); // testing if script to change page url has been executed
});
```

Howerver that only seems to work on the image part. the script has no effect whatsoever.
i also tried to do an
    alert($(nxtHtm).find("script:last-1").html());
and variants such as .text() or . val()
the .html() returns nothing (not "null", it just alerts a blank value) and the other two return null or undefined

Does anyone have an idea of how i can append the remote script here? or alternatively capture the text in between the tags and just eval() it?

thanks ^^

Comment: Sorry, the code should be: `eval($(nxtHtm).find("script").eq(-2).text());` (eq(-1) is the last element). Also, `eq` is only in jquery 1.4+.

Comment: the eq method looked promising, but it still gives the same result though, just a blank string as shown in the screenshot @ http://i69.servimg.com/u/f69/11/39/20/16/ajaxom11.png 

it seems as if the nxtHtm DOM has a blank script element, but i manually verified, the fetched html indeed contains JS code o_O

Answer (score 0):

JQuery will ignore the contents of some elements (e.g. `<head>`), probably in the name of performance. I suspect `<script>` is one of those.

The solution would be to prevent JQuery from parsing the DOM until you've had a chance to override that behaviour.

1. Override JQuery default parsing behaviour with a `converters` block
2. Replace any `<script>` tags with `<div data-tag="script">` so that they're not ignored
3. Find the `text()` of the appropriate div.

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax(nextPage,{
    success: function( data, status, xhr ){
        data = data.replace(/\<script[^>]+\>/ig,"<div data-script='true'>")
        data = data.replace("</script>","</div>")
        var $data = $(data);
        nxtImgUrl = $data.find(".one-page img").attr("src");
        $("body").append("<img id='dynamic' src='"+nxtImgUrl+"'/>");
        $data.find("div[data-script=true]:last-1").text().appendTo("body");
        alert(nextPage);
    },
    converters:{
        "* text": window.String,
        "text html": true,
        "text xml": true
    },
    dataType:'html'
});
```

It's possible that you'll hit encoding problems due to invalid entities like `&`, in which case you may need a RegExp based approach, which is also possible. Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score -1):

search for jsonP or comet programming.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: sometimes life give you hints, not encyclopedias. just be thankful for those